# Вызвать второй запрос после успешного ответа от первого запроса

Tags: c#, xml, httpwebrequest

Работаю с XML запросами, мне надо на консоль вывести ответ от сервера в виде XML формата и ставить условии что после успешного ответа от сервера на первый запрос вызывает второй запрос и потом тоже получить ответ от второго запроса в XML формата. Написал вызов второго запроса внутри условие в методе, правильно ли это? Или где лучше вызвать и как? Коды приведены ниже:

Код после запуска:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string str = Requests.checkPaymentRequisites();
            var xml = postXMLData(url, str);
            Console.WriteLine(xml);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Метод работы с запросом:

```
public static string postXMLData(string destinationUrl, string xml)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destinationUrl);
            byte[] bytes;
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);
            request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            request.Method = "POST";
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse response;
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                var xmlResponce = XmlToResponce(responseStream);
                if (xmlResponce.Providers.checkPaymentRequisites.Payment.result == 0 && xmlResponce.Providers.checkPaymentRequisites.Payment.status==3)

                
             ////     ТУТ ВЫЗЫВАЕТСЯ ВТОРОЙ ЗАПРОС   /////


                string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
                return responseStr;
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
```

Парсинг ответа:

```
private static Responses.Response XmlToResponce (Stream stream)
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Responses.Response));
            var xmlResponce = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream) as Responses.Response;
            return xmlResponce;
        }
```

Comment: `WebRequest` является устаревшим компонентом C# языка, его заменой будет `HttpClient`. Ну а по вопросу - нет, в одном методе не стоит вызывать. В C# пишут все по разным правилам, например есть SOLID, где S - это единственная ответственность. Ну а если вы напишете два запроса в одном методе, то и метод будет ответственен за две разные логики, что превратит ваш код в кашу. Тут лучше делать два отдельных метода, например "получение баланса" и "получение платежей", а уже потом сделать третий метод "получение информации", в котором и будет проверка, успешно выполнен первым метод или нет.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ если делать два отдельных метода "получение баланса" и "получение платежей" каждый раз приходится написать весь код метода postXMLData() повторно на каждом методе, или есть другой вариант?

Comment: `повторно на каждом методе` - зачем вам это? Делаете метод, который принимает абстракцию, и возвращает абстракцию, им и пользуйтесь потом везде, где надо. У вас почти кстати это и есть, уберите из `postXMLData` логику связанную с XML, пусть он возвращает чисто ответ от сервера, либо `Stream`, либо в конце концов `HttpWebResponse` (напомню, что он устарел), а дальше уже в методе условно "получение баланса", вызывайте этот метод, который вернет вам ответ, из которого вы берете уже нужные XML данные. Ну и так все последующие методы. Разбивайте все на свои ответственности.